# how to make my layout like this using react? header row and body rows looking integrated

Tags: reactjs

It is supposed to look like this (the red part means using grid):
[image]

Mine still looks like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```
<Table className="table d-flex row pokemon-detail-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr className="d-flex justify-content-between th-border ">
                            <th scope="col">Waktu</th>
                            <th scope="col">Kegiatan</th>
                            <th scope="col">Catatan</th>
                            <th scope="col">Jumlah</th>
                            <th scope="col">Stok</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr className="d-flex justify-content-between d-flex align-items-center">
                            <td className="">2 Apr 2021, 08:00</td>
                            <td className="table-link">Update Stok</td>
                            <td className="">"Stok Awal"</td>
                            <td className="table-count-stock">+10</td>
                            <td className="table-bold">10</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are applying different set of css for thead tr and tbody tr. I doubt on the css align-items-center applied for tbody is the reason it looks like it is not aligned. However thead and tbody is integrated by default no need to do anything additional.

Hope this helps you debug the issue!!